# Reflect actions for the same object in different windows using Java 3D

Tags: java, java-3d

I'm developing a system in Java 3D, which consists of a main window where I have an object that I can manipulate (rotate, translate), and I have 3 other smaller windows that show different views from this same object, but can't directly manipulate the object.

The next thing I want to do is to reflect the actions I make in the main window to the other windows, in real time.

Does anyone have any idea of how I can proceed in order to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should define cameras fo the other windows in a fixed position, and render the object with the same world matrix, but with the different camera's view and projection. Probablyyou already have a code to render the object, you only need to use different cameras for that.

Without any code it is the most precise answer, I believe.